# apex:dataTable: is it possible to put cancelled jobs at the bottom?

Tags: visualforce, datatable

I have an apex:dataTable to display a table of jobs. In the job object there is a status field. My scenario is I want to display all the cancelled jobs at the bottom of the table. Is it possible to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of the approach that I am familiar to achieve this is use list property

```
List<job> lstcancelledjobs=new List<job>();
List<job> lstotherjobs=new List<job>();
List<job> finallist=new List<job>();
for(job j:lstjobs){
   if(j.status=='Cancelled'){
       lstcancelledjobs.add(j);
   }else{
        lstotherjobs.add(j);
   }
}
 finallist.addAll(lstotherjobs);
 finallist.addAll(lstcancelledjobs);
```

Here Job is assumed object name .Also if cancelled comes last then use SOQL order by Status and ASC

```
[Select Status,Id from Asyncjob order by status ASC];
```

If you prefer not to loop you can use two queries and join them using list Add All property

Comment: Mohith -- don't you mean list addAll() method ?  (not property) -- and the last code fragment is for AsyncJob, not Job__c

Comment: Yes its AddAll method and yes job i clarified.I took as an example and it has to be exact table name

Comment: ah, perhaps - it wasn't clear from OP that it was talking about SFDC async jobs or just 'jobs' as in work orders.